# OneToMany + ManyToMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 main tables (`sellers`, `stores`, `products`), and there is another table for relation between stores and products (`store_product`)

- A **seller** has many **stores** (One to Many relationship)
- A **store** has many **products**, but any of those **products** can be assigned to multiple **stores**, maybe in another seller's stores (Many To Many relationship)

Now, I have a confusion, I want to get all products for a specific seller.

Comment: `Seller::with('stores.products')->get()` should work assuming you have defined the relationships in your models.

Comment: @AngadDubey That query will return so many unwanted records that performance will be incredibly bad, at best. Most likely you'll run out of memory pretty fast...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you defined the reserve of the relationships, you can do:

```php
// your seller's id
$seller_id = 1;

// get your products
$products = Product::whereHas('stores.seller', function ($query) use ($seller_id) {
    $query->where('id', $seller_id);
})->get();
```

## Update

To get the count of products under every seller, you could use the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method, just like this:

```php
$sellers = Seller::withCount(['stores' => function ($query){
    $query->withCount('products');
})->get();
```

which will place a `{relation}_count` column inside the `stores` relationship of your resulting models. In this case, `products_count`:

```php
foreach ($sellers as $seller) {
    echo $seller->stores->first()->products_count;
}
```

Comment: your nice solution works perfectly, thanks a lot, I will try the other solutions to get the best one for performance

Comment: @user9500574 glad to help.

Comment: Can I use this query during selecting all sellers without selecting a specific seller? I want to display the count of products beside the name of each seller

Comment: @user9500574 yeah.. but in that case you'd be searching for all the products.. why not just `$products = Product::all();` (of course, with pagination: `$products = Product::paginate(10);`

Comment: Thanks for your time, I want to select all sellers `$sellers = Seller::all();` then, I want to show the count of products under every seller.

Comment: It doesn't work, I think there isn't a direct relationship between the sellers and the products, so the method of `withCount()` will not work there.

Comment: @user9500574 you are right, I forgot the `stores` table lol. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Fantastic, really I'm very appreciated, thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the builder function `whereHas('relation', $callback)`. With it your query is very straight forward:

```php
$products = Product::query()
    ->whereHas('stores.seller', function ($query) use ($sellerId) {
        $query->where('sellers.id', $sellerId);
    })
    ->get();
```

Apparently using `sellers.id` (where `sellers` is the table name) is important because you most likely have a column called `id` on all three tables. If you omit the table name, the query will fail.